# Account view with MVC and paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

My Model

```
public class AccountListFilterModel
{
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int pagesize { get; set; }
    public string sortOrder { get; set; }
    public string packageTypeFilter { get; set; }
    public string usernameFilter { get; set; }
    public string accountStatusFilter { get; set; }
    public string nameSurnameFilter { get; set; }
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
    public string dateFilter { get; set; }
    public int screenCountFilter { get; set; }

}
```

My Controller

```
 public ViewResult Index(AccountListFilterModel accountListFilter){}
```

My View

```
@{
var currentPageNumber = Request["page"];
var currentPageSize = Request["pagesize"];
var currentSortOrder = Request["sortOrder"];
var currentUsernameFilter = Request["usernameFilter"];
var currentAccountStatusFilter = Request["accountStatusFilter"];
var currentPackageTypeFilter = Request["packageTypeFilter"];
var currentnameSurnameFilter = Request["nameSurnameFilter"];
var currentDateFilter = Request["dateFilter"];
var currentScreenCountFilter = Request["screenCountFilter"];
var currentScreenCountSortFilter = Request["screenCountSortFilter"];}
```

and

```
                <th class="">Account Name
                    <a style="@(currentSortOrder == "UserName desc" ? "" : "display:none;")" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Account", new { pagesize = currentPageSize, sortOrder = "UserName asc", usernameFilter = @currentUsernameFilter, accountStatusFilter = @currentAccountStatusFilter, packageTypeFilter = @currentPackageTypeFilter, dateFilter = @currentDateFilter, screenCountSortFilter = @currentScreenCountSortFilter, screenCountFilter = @currentScreenCountFilter })">
                        <i class="icon-sort-up"></i></a>
                    <a style="@(currentSortOrder == "UserName asc" ? "" : "display:none;")" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Account", new { pagesize = currentPageSize, sortOrder = "UserName desc", usernameFilter = @currentUsernameFilter, accountStatusFilter = @currentAccountStatusFilter, packageTypeFilter = @currentPackageTypeFilter, dateFilter = @currentDateFilter, screenCountSortFilter = @currentScreenCountSortFilter, screenCountFilter = @currentScreenCountFilter,approvedFilter=@currentApprovedFilter })">
                        <i class="icon-sort-down"></i></a>
                    <a style="@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentSortOrder) || !currentSortOrder.StartsWith("UserName") ? "" : "display:none;")" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Account", new { pagesize = currentPageSize, sortOrder = "UserName asc", usernameFilter = @currentUsernameFilter, accountStatusFilter = @currentAccountStatusFilter, packageTypeFilter = @currentPackageTypeFilter,dateFilter = @currentDateFilter, screenCountSortFilter = @currentScreenCountSortFilter, screenCountFilter = @currentScreenCountFilter })">
                        <i class="icon-sort"></i></a>
                </th>
```

How can I shorten my code at View ?

Comment: Seems like you have a lot of logic in your markup, using MVC you're supposed to split these (logic <-> view). Calculate the desired outcome in the controller and pass those values to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass your `AccountListFilterModel` to the view, either via `model` (which is the best solution as it's less error-prone) or using `ViewBag` \ `ViewData` (which is an anti-pattern actually, but fits the quick-fix niche). 
Using the latter approach:

**In your controller:**

```
public ViewResult Index(AccountListFilterModel accountListFilter)
{
    ViewBag.Filter = accountListFilter;
}
```

**In your view** (you can delete the code at the top of the view, that uses `Request` to get parameters.

```
<a style="@(ViewBag.Filter.currentSortOrder == "UserName desc" ? "" : "display:none;")" ... />
```

It's a general rule of thumb that your view should not contain any logic at all, your controller should supply all the data that the view needs.

Comment: Thanks. But What about  @Url.Action("Index", "Account", new { pagesize = currentPageSize, sortOrder = "UserName asc", usernameFilter = @currentUsernameFilter...}. This is the main problem. I change the value and send model. How is be my Url.Action?

Comment: If you change the values, then you have some sort of a form or what?

Comment: I mean my code must be according to your answer: @Url.Action("Index","Account",new{ViewBag.Filter}). But at this action i change the one value of ViewBag.Filter .  Namely, @Url.Action("Index","Account",new{ViewBag.Filter.sortOder="Username asc"}). But at this code i am sending a one parameter. I wanna send amended ViewBag.Filter Model.

Comment: You can just do `@Url.Action("Index", "Account", new { accountListFilter = ViewBag.Filter}`. If you want to change the value, jsut do `ViewBag.Filter.yourvalue = "something"`

Comment: I couldn't tell but thanks enough for me :)

Comment: Using ViewBag is really an anti pattern. You should always use strongly typed view models.

Comment: @SteveMichael I agree with you, but without the knowledge of the OPs architecture it's the best (of the worst) solution. I'll edit the answer to reflect this point